# Is a tear in outer foil of ac duct an issue?

Tags: hvac, ducts

I just noticed a tear in the main duct that goes from the air handler into the ceiling to feed the rest of the duct work.

The tear is in the foil only and I cannot feel any air escaping from it, it looks like the ac was installed and then the painters sprayed the wall of the ac closet and the duct work stuck to it when it dried. Then over the course of wiggles and movement probably pulled off the wall ripping it a little.

So is a slit like this where I cannot feel air coming out a concern? The insulation and whatever ribbing helps hold the duct structure together is fully in tact.

This duct is NOT in the attic.

Comment: It is probably more of a moisture barrier to keep moisture from the insulation.  I would just place some duct(tape made for ducts) over it.  Probably any type of tape will work, masking tape is so-so/iffy.

Comment: use foil tape (i.e. metal tape, nashua foil tape home depot, there's many brands).  no, a slit/tear is not a problem.  It's not leaking air because there is an inner duct that is intact whether its a flex duct or hard sheet metal duct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the duct is for return of warm air, there's little reason to be concerned. If the duct is for *cold* air, though, the tear in the foil would allow moisture from the *surrounding* air to condense *inside* the insulation. This can make the insulation ineffective, and can cause buildup of moisture, inviting fungus and rusting of the metal duct.

If the tear is not too large, just cover the split with duct tape. However, first check that there is no water trapped inside -- if there is, use a hair-dryer to *gently* dry the insulation before taping. The duct tape should be an effective a vapor barrier.

Comment: Use actual aluminum foil duct tape, not the fabric product called the same but much less effective over time.

Comment: Thanks both of you. That’s what I’ll do. You know I actually don’t know if this duct is the return without going to the attic. Would the outside of it physically feel pretty chilly if it was downstream of the handler? Or is it super well insulated to where you couldn’t tell that way? Anyway you answered the other question so I appreciate it!

Comment: @MZawg, when the AC is on, the duct should be noticeably cooler (under the insulation) if it's for cold air outlet. However, if insulation is not wet, then just tape up the tear, since it would make no difference.